# How to make an input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I want to make an "Edit Profile Page" and I made the form for this and the request to the server to give me all the information about a user. The problem is that the field is showing the correct data about the user but I can't modify the data to update the user.

This is how input looks like.

```
   </div> <div className="form-group"
   <label htmlFor="password">Gender</label>
   <input value={this.state.gender} 
           type="text" 
           name="gendre" 
           onChange={this.onChange} 
           className="form-control"  
           placeholder ={ this.props.gender} />
   </div>
```

The *onChange* function is this:

```
onChange = e =>
        this.setState({
          data: { ...this.state.data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }

        });
```

```
state = {
       data: {
         username:this.props.usernameProfile,
         age:'',
         gendre:'',
         location:'',
         zipcode:'',
         faculty:'',
         yearOfFaculty:'',
         userID: this.props.userid



       },
       loading: false,
       errors: {}
     };
```

In the Gender input, it shows "Male"(this comes from the server), but if I want to change it won't let me.

I also tried to write instead `value={this.state.gender}` -> `placeholder={this.state.gender}` and in this way, I can change the value but for example, if I don't want to change it the program will save it as null.

Comment: Could be about your typo on name="gendre" , which should be name="gender"

Comment: Placeholder should not be dynamic. Please remove that logic.

Comment: you're using state as value={this.state.gender}  but you have declared with data:{gender:'}

Comment: @pageNotfoUnd . great catch

Comment: change `value` to `defaultValue`

Answer (score 0):

set gender from props to state. The input value is not the same as the one from props, as it is set to `''` in state;

```
state = {
 ...
 data: { gendre: this.props.gendre ...},
 ...
}
```

And change your input to

```
<input value={this.state.data.gender}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below working example:

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data: {
            username: this.props.usernameProfile,
            age: '',
            gender: '',
            location: '',
            zipcode: '',
            faculty: '',
            yearOfFaculty: '',
            userID: this.props.userid

        },
        loading: false,
        errors: {}
    };
    
    onChange = (e) => {
     const updatedState = {
        ...this.state,
        data: {
        ...this.state.data,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        }
     }
     this.setState(updatedState);
     console.log('state',this.state);

    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
            <label>Gender:</label>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                onChange={this.onChange} 
                name="gender" 
            />
            
            <p>preview: {this.state.data.gender}</p>
            </div>)
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.1.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.1.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></app>
```